# C# Code to Control AutoCAD's Camera

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

In AutoCAD 2015 you can use this camera control to instantly get different views of your model

[image]

And by clicking on an entity or group first and then a part of the cube it'll zoom in onto that entity or group.

[image]

Is there a way to do that programmatically with C#? I want my code to be able to select an entity based on a passed ObjectId and then zoom into it from the top-left-front corner.

Comment: Hi Nick,  From the Manual : http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-FAC1A5EB-2D9E-497B-8FD9-E11D2FF87B93

Answer (score -1):

1. Prompt for object
2. Get its bounding box. Use [this](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/11/creating-the-smallest-possible-rectangle-around-2d-autocad-geometry-using-net.html) for guidance.
3. Then combine with [this](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/06/zooming-to-a-wi.html) to zoom to it.

Comment: The first link you gave me is for 2D objects, that wall is 3D

Comment: And you tell me that you can not get the concept of the enclosing area and then calculating the direction, a.k.a setting the direction vector of the camera? Then because I did not do your homework you vote me down? Nice :)